# SQL Select vale for Column A Row 1, then Value from Column B Row 1, then Column A Row 2...all on separate rows

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have executed a query to create paired combinations of events with the pair as a single row.  See link below for the output.  Column 1 is the ID for the first event and Column 2 is the ID for the paired event.

I need to take this output and then transfer it to rows with only one column.  So basically, rows 1 and 2 would be a pair, rows 3 and 4 would be a pair, etc. Snapshot of desired output in second link below.

Working in SSMS.

Thanks!

[image: Query Output]

[image: Desired Output]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like your original order is by `(fid, sid)`.

`CROSS APPLY` below essentially generates two rows for each original row.
So, we are preserving the original order by `(fid, sid)` and making sure that values from column `fid` come first and from `sid` come second by adding the `SortOrder` column.

```
SELECT
    CA.ID
FROM 
    YourTable
    CROSS APPLY
        (VALUES (fid, 1), (sid, 2)) CA(ID, SortOrder)
ORDER BY
    YourTable.fid,
    YourTable.sid,
    CA.SortOrder;
```

Comment: That worked perfectly.  Thank you so much!  
  
Cross apply is a new function for me.  I appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

This is a rather strange result, because the ordering seems rather arbitrary.  In addition, your original data does not have a stable ordering.  But I think the following is pretty close to what you want:

```
select v.a
from t cross apply
     (values (fid, 1), (sid, 2)) v(a, ord)
order by t.occurrencedate, t.fid, t.sid, v.a, v.ord
```

Comment: Thank you!  This almost got to where I needed.  I agree--it's an oddity, but I needed the pairs in the columns of the original to be rows so that I could use the data in a Python loop.  The ordering seems arbitrary, but it's a combinatorial problem where the second number must be bigger than the first, hence the pattern 1,2; 1,3; 1,4...2,3; 2,4 and so on.

Comment: @cdm . . . You can use `order by t.occurrencedate, t.fid, t.sid, v.a desc`.

Comment: Thank you!  Appreciate the help.